# How to structure my Spring project with Angular frontend?

Tags: spring, angular, directory-structure

I have been looking for a sample structure of a project when you have, for instance, Java/Spring backend and a front end like Angular2.

My first thought was that they will go in two separate top-level folders, like

```
src/
ui/
```

This way I would be treating both as their own apps, like they actually feel (since the logic in angular is going to be different than what is happening at the backend).

But then I thought about the fact that this will make it harder, when browsing the back end, to find what is actually a front-end representation of the given package. So then I thought about using a structure like

```
src/main/java
src/main/javascript
```

And then follow Java-like-package folder structure. This would make it quite easier to see where one thing stands in the UI and what controller/service is responsible for replying to its requests.

However, I can't seem to wrap my mind around which of the two is going to be better for a project going forward. Is there any article/guide that you can recommend me for situations like this (hybrid technologies and project structure, or perhaps this is a specific stack that I'm not aware of and already has some defined good-practices).

Comment: To elaborate on this, I think that angular is more of a standalone app than it is a part of java. Since I won't be using server-side rendering or anything of the sort, my personal opinion is that it should have its own ui folder and just follow similar to java package folder naming. However, I'm not sure that when I get into the project I will see this as a sustainable and scalable structure so I am asking you guys.

Comment: I use a multi-module gradle (but would do the same with Maven) project, with two modules: frontend and backend. The backend has a standard Java/Spring structure. The frontend has a standard angular-cli structure. The gradle tasks of the frontend module just wrap ng commands. The war/jar task of the backend depends on the frontend build, and includes the artefacts generated in the dist folder of the frontend into the war/jar.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the approach from JHipster, where the [Angular2-Structure](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#application-structure-and-angular-modules) is under

```
src/main/webapp/app
```

The advantage is, that you can bundle multiple frontend-technologies in webapp beneath angular, and keep everything seperated but in one project. I think this makes it robust until a high level of compexity.